# MIPS Translation of li pseudo command

Tags: assembly, mips, instructions

When using MIPS assembly code, I have been using the li command a lot to store a constant in a register. However, I am trying to take some of my code and decompose all of the pseudo instructions into normal MIPS instructions.

From research, I understand that li translates into two instructions: lui and ori.

For example,

li $8, 0x3BF20
translates to

lui $8, 0x0003

ori $8, $8, 0xBF20

However, I am not quite sure what lui and ori do, and I am not sure how it produces the same result as li.

Answer (score 2):

`lui` (Load Upper Immediate) is loading the upper half of the register & clearing the lower half; `ori` (OR Immediate) is "loading" the lower half by oring the register w/ the value to go in the lower half.

Answer (score 1):

read the manual, one modifies the whole register half zeros half what you specify the other does a logical or of 16 bits against the register (in this case hitting the other 16 bits that lui zeroed)